# How to make a response body object attributes as a searchable fields in Kibana

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, elk

How to make a response body object attributes of an specific API as a searchable column in Kibana

Is there a way to make it like what we have available fields to filter in left panel of Kibana

Comment: Could you please explain? Your wording is very general. Maybe define a specific case of what you're doing, or what you mean by response body / specific API.

For example, by response body, do you mean the elasticsearch attributes or the ones form your document? by searchable column => what? Document columns are searchable by default (discover tab)

Hope this helps